# How to hide/show progress bar from method onLoadingStateChanged in the FirestorePagingAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

In my app there is a recyclerview with **FirestorePagingAdapter**. In the adapter there is method **onLoadingStateChanged** who is responsible for the loading state. I want to show progress bar while the next page is loading and hide it when it loaded, that's means when **case LOADING_INITIAL** - show progress bar.
The code below will more explain:

```
public class AdAdapter extends FirestorePagingAdapter<Ad, AdAdapter.AdHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<String> imageUrls;
    private ProgressBar homeRecyclerViewProgressBar;

    public AdAdapter(Context context, @NonNull FirestorePagingOptions<Ad> options) {
        super(options);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdAdapter.AdHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_item, viewGroup, false);
        AdHolder vh = new AdHolder(v);
        mContext = viewGroup.getContext();
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Ad model) {

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(model.getTitle());
        holder.textViewPrice.setText(String.valueOf(model.getPrice()));

        imageUrls = model.getImagesUrls();
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(imageUrls.get(0))
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
        super.onLoadingStateChanged(state);

            switch (state) {
            case LOADING_INITIAL:

                homeRecyclerViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // The initial load has begun
                // ...
                Log.d("someLog", "The initial load has begun");
                return;
            case LOADING_MORE:
                // The adapter has started to load an additional page
                // ...
                Log.d("someLog", "The additional load has begun");
                return;
            case LOADED:
                homeRecyclerViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // The previous load (either initial or additional) completed
                // ...
                Log.d("someLog", "Has loaded");
                return;
            case ERROR:
                // The previous load (either initial or additional) failed. Call
                // the retry() method in order to retry the load operation.
                // ...
                Log.d("someLog", "Failed to load");
        }
    }

    class AdHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewTitle;
        TextView textViewPrice;
        ImageView imageView;

        public AdHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textViewTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adTitleMain);
            textViewPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adPriceMain);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            homeRecyclerViewProgressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_recycler_view_progressbar);


        }
    }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
...
switch (state) {
            case LOADING_INITIAL:

                homeRecyclerViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // The initial load has begun
                ........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show/hide your `homeRecyclerViewProgressBar`, please use the following lines of code in your `onLoadingStateChanged()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onLoadingStateChanged(@NonNull LoadingState state) {
    switch (state) {
        case LOADING_INITIAL:
            homeRecyclerViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case LOADING_MORE:
        case LOADED:
            homeRecyclerViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case FINISHED:
            homeRecyclerViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        case ERROR:
            retry();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Alex mamo Thank you very mutch, by the way i watched your videos on youtube). Your solution was helpful for me but relatively, I will explain: when the adapter was separately in file it not worked, but when i put adapter in a function in the fragment it work for me.

Comment: Hi again and you're welcome :) Good to hear that it was helpful and thanks for watching my tutorials.